# how to get the value of button without using function in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor this is how I kept the button in html file.

```
<input type="button" class="number" value="1">
<input type="button" class="number" value="2">
<input type="button" class="number" value="3">
```

How to get the value of these buttons in the js file.

Any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use meteors event-handler. check my answer for a clean solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value using an event:

```
'click .number': function(event, template) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

Or plain Jquery:

```
$($('.number')[0]).val()
$($('.number')[1]).val()
$($('.number')[2]).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

well to determine which buttons get clicked you can simply use event handlers for your template. And its very important to know that the buttons are identified through their class names. Therefor you have to **choose unique classnames**.

For example if you have the buttons inside a template called `template1` you just do the following:

```
//in your .html inside your template1

<button class="button1">Button1</button>
<button class="button2">Button2</button>
<button class="button3">Button3</button>
```

and the corresponding JS:

```
//in your clientside JS

Template.template1.events({
  "click.button1": function () {
    //exec code when button1 clicked
    //[...]
  },
  "click.button2": function () {
    //exec code when button2 clicked
    //[...]
  },
  "click.button3": function () {
    //exec code when button3 clicked
    //[...]
  }
});
```

if your buttons aren't in an template, but just inside your  just use the area as template. for example **`Template.body.events`** will handle events in your body.

Comment: Below method is useful for my situation. i dont want different class for each button. this may useful for someone else. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like below:

```
Template.TemplateName.events({
 'click .number': function (event,template) {
     return event.target.value;
 }
});
```

Comment: event.target.value or event.currentTarget.value works well. Thank you for your response. I didnt pass that event to the function so it returns unknown error. now it works right. thank you.